# When first passed array to constructor is updated

Tags: java

How is the process when a constructor parameter is a list and list is updated through an external function? There is "pass-by-reference" system when parameter is an array or list. But how is the object updated? Is any copy constructor used or how?

Let's assume that we have two user-defined classes Point and Curve. We filled our list with Point objects. Then we construct our Curve object with List of Points.

```
List<Point> points=new ArrayList<>();
points.add(Point(0,1));
points.add(Point(0,0));
Curve c=new Curve(points);
```

Then we add a Point object to our List of Points.

```
points.add(Point(1,1));
```

How is Curve object is affected?

Comment: *`points.Add` typo `points.add`

Comment: The curve object now has 3 points in the List. Everything in java is passed by value, the reference of the curve object is not the same as `points`, but points(haha) to the same List.

Comment: @user3719857 we can't entirely know that's true without seeing the code for `Curve`. If the constructor is making a deep copy of the list, then adding to `points` will not affect it.

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 actually that's the answer I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is just a `pass-reference-by-value` but no pure `pass-by-reference` in java. If `Curve` stores the original value to the reference of `points` and `points` is not reinitialized then you are still working on the same reference and hence the `List` in `c` would also change(it´s still the same reference).

Here is a small example that should show you when you are working on the same reference and when not.

```
public class Curve{

    private List<Point> points = new ArrayList<>(0);

    public Curve(List<Point> points) {
        this.points = points;
    }

    public Curve(List<Point> points, boolean flag) {
        this.points.addAll(points);
    }

    void print() {
        for(Point p : points) {
            System.out.println(p);
        }
    }

    public static class Point {
        int x;
        int y;
        public Point(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "X = " + x +"\nY = " + y ;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Curve.Point> points = new ArrayList<Curve.Point>(0);
        points.add(new Curve.Point(0,0));
        points.add(new Curve.Point(0,1));
        // Care for compiler error just one should be used
        Curve c = new Curve(points,true); // Using this constructor copies the elements and the folloing add wont affect c
        Curve c = new Curve(points); // Using this constructor uses the same list so the following add will affect c
        points.add(new Curve.Point(1,1));
        c.print();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It is more clear to me :)

Comment: Kevin, it's worth noting that your `boolean flag` doesn't actually accomplish anything other than denoting a new constructor method signature. If you really wanted to, you could make a value of `true` copy the list and value of `false` merely assign the reference internally.

Answer (score 0):

c is essentially a pointer to the points object. Meaning the "value" of c internally contains the address of "points" object somewhere in the class.

From here on out, the changes you make in the points object will reflect over to the c object.

Comment: This is *wrong*! `c` is *not* a pointer to `points`, it's its own Object! `points` was merely passed as an argument to `Curve`, and we can't make the assertion that the reference to `points` remains inside `Curve` without seeing the source code for the `Curve` class (or viewing how `c` is affected after the `add` operation). If the constructor is making a deep copy of the list, then adding to points will not affect it.